# What is the most efficient way to clone a fixed-sized array?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that consists of a fixed-size byte array with 65536 elements.

I've implemented `Clone` on my struct naively — I create a new array and loop through the original, copying each element one-at-a-time.  Is there a more efficient or idiomatic way of doing this that would essentially boil down to a `memcpy`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Since Rust 1.21

Arrays of items that are `Clone` always implement `Clone`, so you can simply call `.clone()` on the array, or `#[derive(Clone)]` on the struct.

### Before Rust 1.21

As of Rust 1.12, arrays only implement `Clone` for up to 32 items. However, arrays implement `Copy` for any number of items (despite `Copy` requiring `Clone`!). We can therefore make an implicit copy of the array in our implementation of `Clone`.

```
struct Foo {
    b: [u8; 65536],
}

impl Clone for Foo {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Foo {
            b: self.b
        }
    }
}
```

If you also want your struct to implement `Copy`, then you can also implement `Clone::clone` by just making a copy of `self`:

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct Foo {
    b: [u8; 65536],
}

impl Clone for Foo {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        *self
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I don't want my struct to have copy semantics so the first solution is exactly what I'm looking for.